# AWS Appstream - cannot create managed image updates

Tags: aws-appstream

I'm trying to install Windows Updates on my AWS Appstream image using "Managed Image Updates". No matter if I do it from Console or CLI I received the follwing error:

"Error. Image  is already up to date for account . Try again later."

from CLI

aws appstream create-updated-image  --existing-image-name  --new-image-name  --new-image-display-name

"An error occurred (OperationNotPermittedException) when calling the CreateUpdatedImage operation: Image is already up to date for account. Try again later."

I'm looking for the reason of failure. I know that this image is missing at least patches for the last two months.

Very appreciate any help ;)

Cris